# Dedekind's criterion clarification

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals, dedekind-domain

Dedekind's criterion gives a way of factoring $p\mathcal{O}_K$ into prime ideals. (See http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/154Page/handouts/dedekindcrit.pdf)

Is it true that the prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i := (p, h_i(\alpha))$ are distinct? Why?

Comment: Yes, it is implicit that those ideals are distinct.  They are in one-to-one correspondence with the irreducible factors $h_i$ in the theorem. To see those ideals are distinct, assume $(p,h_i(\alpha)) = (p,h_j(\alpha))$. Then working modulo this prime ideal, we are in a field of characteristic $p$ where $\overline{h}_i(X)$ and $\overline{h}_j(X)$ have the common root $\overline{\alpha}$ (reduction of $\alpha$). But it's implicit when writing the monic irreducible factorization that the $h_i$'s are distinct, and distinct monic irreducibles don't have a common root. Contradiction!

Comment: Anyone knows why in this paper when the discriminant is square free then $\mathcal O_k=\Bbb Z[\alpha]$?